# PyInstaller Problem

Tags: python, executable, pyinstaller

I created an exe version of my python program with pyinstaller. But When I try to run my app from 
that exe I get an error like this:

[image]

What may the problem be caused from?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Hi, did you find a solution? Because I face the same concern, which is really annoying. I opened a question for my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838606/pyinstaller-seems-not-to-find-a-data-file

Comment: Are you able to run your code if you package it with the one-folder method instead of one-file?  Could help narrow it down.