# pyinstaller seems not to find a data file

Tags: python, pyinstaller

Edit 3: I replaced `__file__` with `sys.argv[0]`, when I need to know the location of my script/executable. This is not exactly the same, but in my case it seems to run fine (at least on executable version...). Now everything is working fine, in one-file mode, with use of accepted answer's function to access resource files!

---

Edit 2: as shown in accepted answer's comments, problem is coming from path resolution in my script; I try to use `__file__` to get the location of the script, so that I can access to its resource files. This does not work once packaged, as `__file__` will return filename from `Python.dll` to the script, so quite always no path and just a file name. So I have to find another trick to make access to resource files; a work-around for the moment is to move current directory to the executable path.

By the way, this means that the ConfigParser should report problem when accessing the file, and not that a section is missing.

I'll update this question with the way I resolved this path resolution question.

---

I've got problems with `pyinstaller`, and as it's the first time I'm using it, it's sure that I've done something wrong.

So, here's the problem: `pyisntaller` runs smoothly on a script I wrote, and generates some stuff in `dist` folder. Ok, so now I want to execute it to see if all went well, and here's what I get:

```
C:\Program Files\PyInstaller\pyinstaller-1.5.1>p_tool\dist\p_tool\p_tool.exe -?
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 104, in <module>
  File "p_tool\build\pyi.win32\p_tool\outPYZ1.pyz/logging.config", line 76, in f
ileConfig
  File "p_tool\build\pyi.win32\p_tool\outPYZ1.pyz/logging.config", line 112, in
_create_formatters
  File "p_tool\build\pyi.win32\p_tool\outPYZ1.pyz/ConfigParser", line 532, in ge
t
ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'
```

My first idea was that the `logging.conf` file was missing, so I added it (and some other resource files) in the `p_tool.spec` file, but this is not better.

Python version: 2.6.6, under WinXP. I'm using `pyinstaller` as I will need it to package files for a Solaris workstation.

So, anyone did have this problem? The only topic related is the following question: [PyInstaller Problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6569896/pyinstaller-problem), really close to my problem, but hopelessly it got no answer.

---

Edit3: details about logging removed, as not really related to the problem.

Comment: this seems a better solution:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/404744/determining-application-path-in-a-python-exe-generated-by-pyinstaller/404750#404750

Comment: Correct, thanks for the link!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Firstly, it might be wise to do a print config_file / os.path.exists(config_file) before reading it, so you can be sure where the file is and if python can find it.

As to actually accessing it, `os.path.split(__file__)` looks almost correct, but I'm not sure it works properly under pyinstaller - the proper way of packing files is to add them to the .spec file, pyinstaller will then load them at compile time and unpack them to $_MEIPASS2/ at run time. To get the _MEIPASS2 dir in packed-mode and use the local directory in unpacked (development) mode, I use this:

```
def resource_path(relative):
    return os.path.join(
        os.environ.get(
            "_MEIPASS2",
            os.path.abspath(".")
        ),
        relative
    )


# in development
>>> resource_path("logging.conf")
"/home/shish/src/my_app/logging.conf"

# in deployment
>>> resource_path("logging.conf")
"/tmp/_MEI34121/logging.conf"
```

Comment: This answer is full of good advice. So, first, printing the path I'm looking for is showing that `__file__` is resolved as the script, relative to `Python.dll`, which means that in my case, `os.path.split(...)[0]` is always empty. Said otherwise, it's as if my script would be local to any location where it's called... So now I have to find out another way to access my resource files. :-/

Comment: To complete previous comment: if I move to executable folder before executing it, path resolution is fine, and now tool starts correctly! So, now I have to understand how to define the path resolution inside my Python code to make it work, and it's another topic. About `resource_path` function, it'll surely be useful when I'll try one-file packaging. So, your answer is worth the bounty! Thanks for your help :-)

Comment: MEIPASS or MEIPASS2? How do I know?

Answer (score 0):

The error message `ConfigParser.NoSectionError: No section: 'formatters'` suggests that it's not a missing file but a file with a missing section that you should be looking for.

Comment: I updated the question, but I doubt it's really a problem from this file, as Python version runs without problem. So I think that's more a problem with access to the file.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem but couldn't find a elegant fix so far. The 'hack' I use that got me trough, say my project is located in `'~/project/project_root'`, first in the .spec file:

```
excluded_sources = TOC([x for x in a.pure if not x[0].startswith('project_root')])
```

Here a is the `Analysis` object, basically I remove all of my projects files from the `PYZ` so no import is passed there and the logger's relative paths won't be computed from there. After this, create a `Tree` object from the project.

```
my_project_tree = Tree('~/project')
```

Then add this Tree to the list of TOC that is passed to COLLECT, so :

```
COLLECT( exe,
           a.binaries,
           a.zipfiles,
           a.datas,
           my_project_tree,
           ....)
```

You should have your project folder added to the dist folder. The problem is that you'll end up distributing the pyc's of your project too, but couldn't find a better way so far. Very interested in the valid solution.

Comment: Mmh ok, seems tricky but not beyond my reach. Question though: will the `pyc` files be executed with the embedded Python executable? I mean, will this run on any computer with or without Python installed?

Comment: Yes they should be, as long as it's the same os. I've only tested it on debian squeeze however so can't guarantee.

Comment: I added some more details about logging configuration. Could you please have a look? Maybe the way I configured my resource files is leading to problems with `PyInstaller`.

Comment: Second comment, about your code: are you using the `excluded_sources` as follows: `pyz = PYZ(a.pure - excluded_sources)`? If yes, then maybe the `not` is too many in `for x in a.pure if *not* x[0].startswith(...`. I may have not understood it, as it's still not working; but having `pyc` files is still better than nothing, if packaged for any Python version.

Comment: Here're some news. Problem was coming from the fact that `__file__` was not returning the expected value. So, I end up using `sys.argv[0]` to determine location of the called executable. I hope there's no side-effect about this, as it's all I could imagine to work-around this issue. Thanks for your help anyway!

Comment: @Bogdan: Your hack worked for me on Windows. I have a question though. After I run pyinstaller after making some changes to my python scripts, won't I need to run pyinstaller again against the .py file to generate a new spec? If so, then I will need to make these changes each time I make changes to the script before I build an exe. Is there a way around that?