# google drive api crash with desktop application

Tags: python, google-drive-api, pyinstaller, google-api-python-client

I use google drive application wrote a desktop application using python and everything works fine. But when I use pyinstaller to output a .exe file and run that application. A problem occurs on these lines:

```
if credentials is None or credentials.invalid:
  credentials = run(FLOW, storage)
```

The authentication page shows and I allow its access. Unlike usual, there is no response after that and I found that the .exe program exits with no reason.
Anyone met this problem before? If so, how to solve it?

P.S. I traced the error now and it is as follows:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 697, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 562, in __init__
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\tools.py", line 166, in run
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\oauth2client\client.py", line 1069, in step2_exchange
  File "USB\build\pyi.win32\USB\outPYZ1.pyz/httplib2", line 1544, in request
  File "USB\build\pyi.win32\USB\outPYZ1.pyz/httplib2", line 1294, in _request
  File "USB\build\pyi.win32\USB\outPYZ1.pyz/httplib2", line 1230, in _conn_request
  File "USB\build\pyi.win32\USB\outPYZ1.pyz/httplib2", line 984, in connect
  File "USB\build\pyi.win32\USB\outPYZ1.pyz/httplib2", line 80, in _ssl_wrap_socket
  File "USB\build\pyi.win32\USB\outPYZ1.pyz/ssl", line 381, in wrap_socket
  File "USB\build\pyi.win32\USB\outPYZ1.pyz/ssl", line 141, in __init__
       ssl.SSLError: [Errno 185090050] _ssl.c:340: error:0B084002:x509 certificate rout
       ines:X509_load_cert_crl_file:system lib
```

I saw someone encountered the similar error http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=58 but the reply said it already fixed it.
I also tried the method in https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/issues/557 but it is not working.
Does anyone know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After digging a little bit, I found the solution based on solution provided by Dropbox api developer: https://forums.dropbox.com/topic.php?id=65523&replies=1#post-461457. This problem is basically caused by:

```
 CA_CERTS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__ )), "cacerts.txt")

__file__ is the key that causes this problem. It cannot work normally in the executable program to find the path.
```

Similar problem can be found here: [pyinstaller seems not to find a data file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7838606/pyinstaller-seems-not-to-find-a-data-file)

In order to solve this problem, I change the above code into this:

```
 CA_CERTS = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(sys.executable), "cacerts.txt")
```

By doing this, the .exe program will try to find cacerts.txt in the directory where .exe file is located. After compiling this into .pyc, I put cacerts.txt into .exe directory. Then the program can run normally.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing, but this is possible related to STDIN handling on Windows exe from pyinstaller - usually this won't be available to you, so you might have to run your own custom flow.

But you can narrow it down to either:

1. Reading/writing from STDIN/STDOUT
2. Starting a local web server
3. Launching a browser

Since all those need to be performed when running a flow locally, and one of them is going wrong for you.

If you log STDERR to a text file, you will be able to see which part is crashing.

Comment: Actually the program can launch the web browser with authentication page but after clicking allow, it is supposed to continue but it just exits with no warning or error message. Would you mind telling me how to log STDERR?

Comment: Sorry, I'm not familiar with pyinstaller. http://www.pyinstaller.org/export/develop/project/doc/Manual.html?format=raw has some info.