PyInstaller unable to open image file in Python Turtle program
The error message tkinter. TclError: couldn 't open "boiled-egg.gif": no such file or directory [3792] Failed to execute script 'main' due to unhandled exception!
I'm trying to create an executable from my Python Turtle program using PyInstaller. My program uses an image called boiled-egg.gif, but when I run the executable, I get the error.
class Food(Turtle):
def __init__(self):
super().__init__()      # Call the Turtle class constructor
self.shape("boiled-egg.gif")    # Set the shape of the food object to the image file
self.penup()
self.speed("fastest")
self.goto(Random().randint(-280, 280), Random().randint(-280, 280)) # Set the initial position of the food object
self.refresh()  # Call the refresh method

I was expecting the image of the food turtle is set to a gif called "boiled-egg.gif" which is there in the directory alongside the main.py. The program is running fine inside the console/terminal, however, when made into one executable file with Pyinstaller or auto-py-to-exe, it gives the error shown in the image. One more thing, when made into executable without the external image, shape set to "turtle", the executable file works well.
OS - Mac
Python version - 3.12.3
Pyinstaller version - 6.9.0

Welcome to SO! Please provide a [mre] in an [edit] - the code you've provided isn't runnable because of indentation issues, and we can't really reproduce your error without knowing your directory structure at the very least.

Try directing the data in the pyinstaller spec after running pyinstaller as follows (from user folder):
datas=[('PythonIDEProjects_folder/YourProject/boiled-egg.gif', '.')],


Correction: This does not work for pyinstaller: it does not provide path for turtle.shape image. I only get exe to work so far if turtle.shape image is also in user folder.

I tried that too, but it still shows the same error. I have tried too many things to be honest and it still doesn't work. I guess I would have to share the screen to someone in real time to fix it.

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73035011/bundling-images-into-pyinstaller
